# Where are Firefox bookmarks stored in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp

Where are Firefox bookmarks stored in Windows XP?

I've already checked `C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\Application Data\` and there is no Firefox folder, only one called *Microsoft*. I've read everywhere I should look for it in this folder, but there is nothing there, however I can see my bookmarks by displaying the drop-down menu on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Firefox, select *Help » Troubleshooting Information* or go to `about:support`. Click the button *Open Containing Folder* in *Application Basics*. There is your profile directory, and it contains a file `bookmarks.html`.

Comment: I have already enabled displaying hidden files and folders and there is no Mozilla folder

Comment: @jose Are you looking in `Local Settings` like I wrote?

Comment: I don't have a folder called `Local Settings`

Comment: @jose Does my new description help you?

Comment: yes, many thanks, I finally found Application Data folder through about:support, it was hidden. There should be something wrong with my windows because despite selecting the Show all files radio button and pressing the apply button the hidden files are not shown. When I select the view tab again the Show all files radio buton appears unselected. I managed to recover my old bookmarks in the ..\Profiles\ln0ql7ls.default\bookmarkbackups directory